# convert a binary std::stringstream content to base64 (and back) with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, base64, armadillo, qbytearray

i'd like to save some armadillo matrix in a json file, once base64 encoded.
Here is an uncomplete code sample on whitch I'm working.
My problem is converting from std::stringstream to QByteArray and back whithout loosing my stringstream original (exact) content.

```
arma::file_type arma_save_format=arma::arma_binary;
std::stringstream savemedium;

//init & save
{
    std::stringstream ss1;
    arma::mat m;
    m<<1<<2<<3<<arma::endr<<4<<5<<6<<arma::endr<<7<<8<<9;
    std::cout<<"#1 m:"<<m<<std::endl;
    m.save(ss1, arma_save_format);
    savemedium<<ss1.str();
}

/*************************/
std::cout<<"inter:"<<savemedium.str()<<std::endl<<std::endl;
QByteArray ba1;

//here I'd like to convert savemedium to a base64 QString, probably using a qbyteArray,
//and convert it back to std::stringstream savemedium


savemedium.str("");
savemedium<< /* ?? */;

std::cout<<"inter:"<<savemedium.str()<<std::endl<<std::endl;
/*************************/
//restitution
{
    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss2<<savemedium.str();
    arma::mat m2;
    m2.load(ss2, arma_save_format);
    std::cout<<"#2:"<<m2<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using QByteArray's `append` method with a `QString` argument? You can use `QString`'s `fromStdString` to convert from a `std::string` to a `QString`. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#append-2

Comment: Yes, I tried some of those without success. This works until i try to get my original string back in my std::stringstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I got it work:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <sstream>


// to print the content of a QByteArray
void print(const QByteArray &ba) {
    QByteArray::const_iterator it=ba.begin();
    uint i=0;
    while (it!=ba.end()) {
        std::cout<<ba.at(i);
        i++;
        it++;
    }
}

int main(int, char **) {
arma::file_type arma_save_format=arma::arma_binary;
std::stringstream savemedium;

//init & save
{
    std::stringstream ss1;
    arma::mat m;
    m<<1<<2<<3<<arma::endr<<4<<5<<6<<arma::endr<<7<<8<<9;
    std::cout<<"#1 m:"<<m<<std::endl;
    m.save(ss1, arma_save_format);
    savemedium<<ss1.str();
}


/*************************/
std::cout<<"savemedium:"<<std::endl<<savemedium.str()<<std::endl<<std::endl;

//  Here I'd like to convert savemedium to a base64 QString, probably using a qbyteArray,
//  and convert it back to std::stringstream savemedium
//  the following block commented, savemedium is left unmodified and I get the matrix back.
{
    QByteArray ba1;
    ba1.setRawData(savemedium.str().c_str(), savemedium.str().size());

    print(ba1);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"ba1 count:"<<ba1.count()<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    QByteArray b64(ba1.toBase64());

    std::cout<<"b64:"<<std::endl;
    print(b64);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    QByteArray ba2(QByteArray::fromBase64(b64));
    std::cout<<"ba2:"<<std::endl;
    print(ba2);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"ba2 count:"<<ba2.count()<<std::endl<<std::endl;


    std::cout<<"What we get if we just use QByteArray::data()"<<std::endl<<"ba2:"<<std::endl<<ba2.data()<<std::endl;

    savemedium.str(""); //emptying savemedium so we fill it with decoded data

    QByteArray & ba=ba2;    //just a reference for typing comfort

    QByteArray::const_iterator it=ba.begin();
    uint i=0;
    while (it!=ba.end()) {
        savemedium<<ba.at(i);
        i++;
        it++;
    }
}
std::cout<<"savemedium:"<<std::endl<<savemedium.str()<<std::endl<<std::endl;
/*************************/
//restitution
{
    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss2<<savemedium.str();
    arma::mat m2;
    m2.load(ss2, arma_save_format);
    std::cout<<"#2:"<<m2<<std::endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

This gives the folowwing output:

```
#1 m:   1.0000   2.0000   3.0000
   4.0000   5.0000   6.0000
   7.0000   8.0000   9.0000

savemedium:
ARMA_MAT_BIN_FN008
3 3
�?@@@@ @@"@

ARMA_MAT_BIN_FN008
3 3
�?@@@@ @@"@
ba1 count:95

b64:
QVJNQV9NQVRfQklOX0ZOMDA4CjMgMwoAAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAHEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAABRAAAAAAAAAIEAAAAAAAAAIQAAAAAAAABhAAAAAAAAAIkA=

ba2:
ARMA_MAT_BIN_FN008
3 3
�?@@@@ @@"@
ba2 count:95

What we get if we just use QByteArray::data()
ba2:
ARMA_MAT_BIN_FN008
3 3

savemedium:
ARMA_MAT_BIN_FN008
3 3
�?@@@@ @@"@

#2:   1.0000   2.0000   3.0000
   4.0000   5.0000   6.0000
   7.0000   8.0000   9.0000

Press  to close this window...
```

I used QByteArray as it has base64 encoding methods, and std::stringstream because armadillo mat::load() or save handle streams.

QByteArray can't be fed safely with binary data using << or append(), this truncates the data when meeting some special characters (i suppose '\0').

That's the reason of using:

```
ba1.setRawData(savemedium.str().c_str(), savemedium.str().size());
```

Once the data is in the QByteArray, it isn't trivial to retrieve it
to put it in a stringstream:
I did this so:

```
  QByteArray::const_iterator it=ba.begin();
    uint i=0;
    while (it!=ba.end()) {
        savemedium<<ba.at(i);
        i++;
        it++;
    }
```

Any better solution welcome. Using QByteArray::data() truncates the binary data as well, probably for the same reasons.
Thanks for answers and comments.